# avoiding NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, multithreading, exception, networking, networkonmainthread

I've understood that a network operation is not allowed on the GUI thread. Ok for me. But why using this code on a Dialog button click callback still produce `NetworkOnMainThreadException` ?

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {                         
  @Override
  public void run() {
    heavyAndTimeConsumingOperation();
  }
}).run();
```

perhaps i'm not spawning a new thread this way?

Comment: Check out my **[blog post on the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)** for more information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call `.start()`, not `.run()`.

`.run()` is the method you override that actually executes.
`.start()` is a system-provided method that actually starts a thread.

Comment: Hmmm... can i change this stupid question with a new one concerning space-time matrix?

Answer (score 4):

SLaks is right, but for Android there is a more delicate way: [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
        //Do heavy stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        //Do UI stuff after heavy stuff
    }
}.execute();
```