# Eerror downloading file httppost

Tags: android, file, download

I need to download a json file from web. Firstly I want to say that the link that I use is valid.
Here is the code:

```
private String getJsonFromUrl(String url) {
        String json = null;

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            json = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // return json
        return json;
    }
```

The problem is that I receive an error:

```
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.player/com.example.player.PlaySongActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2185)
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
01-01 15:52:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at com.example.player.DBManagement.LastFM.getJsonFromUrl(LastFM.java:243)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NetworkOnMainThreadException` - You can not run your network stuff on the main UI thread. You need to start a new thread to run your httpPost, or else work around by fiddling with strict mode.  Search stack overflow. There are many answers to this question. Here's an answer
[avoiding NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11084755/1689695)